# Override required field in openApi eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, schema, openapi

Good afternoon, I use one model for several endpoints, Java classes already have schemas for models and their fields. I need to override a field for only one of my endpoints, which is listed as "required" (`required=true`), to `required = false`. How can this be done using open api annotations?

I use eclipse open api implementation.
example:

```
Response myEndpoint(Request request){
 ...
}

<p>@Schema</p>
Request
<p></p>
<p> @Schema(required = true)</p>
<p>-RequestBusinessData businessData;</p>
<p></p>
<p>@Schema</p>
<p>RequestBusinessData</p>
<p></p>
<p> @Schema(required = true)</p>
<p>-Product product;</p>
<p></p>
```

But for my endpoint Schem request, i want see "product" be `required=false`

Comment: Are you the author of the endpoint or is this an external endpoint somewhere you're trying to use? The field is required for a reason. You cannot decide that it should not be required unless you're the author in control of the endpoint.

Comment: @Maritim that's right, I am the author of one endpoint, but there are other endpoints that are not mine and that also use the same data model where the product is actually required = true. Is there a way to override only my endpoint? how?